# Gas heater lights then goes out

Tags: natural-gas

The machine turns on and trying to light and then shuts down does this about three times then stops , starts again but doesn’t seem like anything lights up who to call ? What kind of problem ?

Comment: What make and model is the heater, and does it use a standing pilot for ignition, or some sort of electrical hot-surface or spark igniter?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a defective thermocouple, a sensor to measure the temperature (either it can be too far away the pilot, push it close to it if the case, or is already defective, you could replace it).

You could also check the pilot tube, it can be blocked.